# How to theme Material UI inside Storybook

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, storybook

Currently this is what I am doing, passing a `ThemeProvider` above my component file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { ThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import MUIButton from '@material-ui/core/Button';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "#ff0000"
    }
  },
  typography: {
    fontFamily: 'Nunito Sans, sans-serif',
    button: {
      textTransform: 'none'
    }
  },
  shape: {
    borderRadius: 3
  }
})


export default ({ variant, children }) => {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <MUIButton
        color="primary"
        variant={variant}
      >
        {children}
      </MUIButton>
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}
```

I am trying to figure out how I can do this at a global level in Storybook. This is the first component I have built out called `Button`. So I want to be able to have the theme in an external file, and have the `ThemeProvider` coming in at a higher level so I don't have to wrap each component. Hope that makes sense, and if anyone has any ideas.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

First, I suggest you to move your theme into a separate file (such as `src/stylesheet` so you can access it from different files (your global `App` component and your storybook preview file).

```
// src/stylesheet.ts

import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

export const muiTheme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "#ff0000"
    }
  },
  typography: {
    fontFamily: 'Nunito Sans, sans-serif',
    button: {
      textTransform: 'none'
    }
  },
  shape: {
    borderRadius: 3
  }
})
```

Then, you need to setup your storybook the same way you set up your react app. To do so, try to create a file called:
`.storybook/preview.js` and put this inside of it:

```
// .storybook/preview.js

import React from 'react';

import { addDecorator } from '@storybook/react';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

import { muiTheme } from '../src/stylesheet';

addDecorator((story) => (
    <ThemeProvider theme={muiTheme}>{story()}</ThemeProvider>
));
```

It will wrap all your stories inside of the `ThemeProvider`.

In your app, you can can also have a global `App` component which will encapsulate the whole app within the `ThemeProvider`

More help:
https://storybook.js.org/docs/basics/writing-stories/

Comment: For the new version of Storybook v6 uses like that export const decorators = [<ThemeProvider theme={muiTheme}>{story()}</ThemeProvider>]

Answer (score 20):

This is the only solution that worked for me with MUI v5:

```
// .storybook/main.js

const path = require('path');
const toPath = (filePath) => path.join(process.cwd(), filePath);

module.exports = {
   webpackFinal: async (config) => {
    return {
       ...config,
      resolve: {
         ...config.resolve,
        alias: {
          ...config.resolve.alias,
          '@emotion/core': toPath('node_modules/@emotion/react'),
          'emotion-theming': toPath('node_modules/@emotion/react'),
        },
      },
    };
  },
};


// .storybook/preview.js

import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { ThemeProvider as Emotion10ThemeProvider } from 'emotion-theming';

const defaultTheme = createTheme(); // or your custom theme

const withThemeProvider = (Story, context) => {
  return (
    <Emotion10ThemeProvider theme={defaultTheme}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={defaultTheme}>
        <Story {...context} />
      </ThemeProvider>
    </Emotion10ThemeProvider>
  );
};

export const decorators = [withThemeProvider];

// ...other storybook exports
```

It's from the MUI migration guide but it took me unnecessarily long to find so I want to share it here:
https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4/

Comment: Yes, the only solution that worked! Thanks!

Comment: only `Emotion10ThemeProvider` wrapper  was needed in the `preview.js` in order to make this work in my case (no need to change `/main.js` config file)

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right! this is the only solution that truly propagates down MUI V5 theme(including RTL support)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks! Not .storybook/main.js configuration was needed it.  The Emotion10ThemeProvider was enough for my case to work.

Comment: This worked for me with MUI v5

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me with the latest versions of Mui and Storybook! You are a lifesaver!

Answer (score 13):

For Storybook 6.3+ it should look like the following

Update preview.js with:

```
import React from 'react';
import { theme } from './src/theme'; // whereever you have defined your material ui theme

export const decorators = [
  Story => (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Story />
    </ThemeProvider>
  ),
];
```

More details on how to decorate your stories here:
https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/writing-stories/decorators

And creating your theme for Material UI here:
https://material-ui.com/customization/theming/

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is the most up to date answer... and the cleanest, updating `path/to/your/Theme` with your path

```
// .storybook/preview.js

import React from 'react';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/system';
import { Theme } from 'path/to/your/Theme';

export const decorators = [
  (Story) => (
    <ThemeProvider theme={Theme}>
      <Story />
    </ThemeProvider>
  ),
];
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me with react-router and mui V5

my preview.js =>

```
import React from 'react';
import { addDecorator } from '@storybook/react';
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { ThemeProvider as Emotion10ThemeProvider } from 'emotion-theming';
import customTheme from '../src/theme/index';

addDecorator((story) => (
    <Emotion10ThemeProvider theme={customTheme}>
        <ThemeProvider theme={customTheme}>
            <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/']}>{story()}</MemoryRouter>
        </ThemeProvider>
    </Emotion10ThemeProvider>
));

export const parameters = {
    actions: { argTypesRegex: '^on[A-Z].*' },
    controls: {
        matchers: {
            color: /(background|color)$/i,
            date: /Date$/,
        },
    },
};
```